# AS3 Fisheye Effect

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having trouble understand how `DisplacementMapFilter` works. Basically, I'm trying to create a revolving planet through a combination of fisheye/masking.

Also, how do I go about doing this via timeline? I'm not too familiar with coding within it, but this is more of an animation project than anything else, so classes are out of the question. Sorry for the lack of code -- I'm simply stuck.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/DisplacementMapFilter.html and examples? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/DisplacementMapFilter.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: @Dave I have, but I don't see how you can create a fisheye effect based on the example.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're stuck, so I'll assume it's in generating the image. Put simply, if you use red for x and green for y, then dark yellow (128,128,anything) will mean don't move, and dark red (128,0,anything) will mean use the full y displacement, etc. So you need to consider how you want each pixel to move. There is a simple way of doing this in image editing tools, but it's too long to explain in a comment. If I'm right that this is your problem let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @Dave Pretty much. I have CS5 if that helps (although I'm certain that there's no easy way to do it without using code).

Comment: Well I have no idea about doing it without code; I've only ever made Flash files with pure code (I don't own the IDE). I'll post an answer explaining how you can make the image, but it sounds like you need more help than that. I'd suggest *not* marking it as an answer and waiting for someone else to explain the rest.

Comment: @Dave Sorry, I was asking how to do it with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments above, this probably only answers half the problem;

Generating a displacement map image isn't too difficult with the right tools. I'll assume you're using Photoshop, GIMP, Fireworks, or similar.

It's probably best to work on a 128x128 image or smaller with this method. Some editors have more specialised tools which let you work on pretty much any size of image, but this is a generic process that needs no special tools. You can always enlarge the end result, but the quality will begin to go down.

- Start with a gradient fill. It should go from pure black on the left to dark red on the right (specifically 128,0,0). Add a vertical fill from black at the top to dark green at the bottom (specifically 0,128,0), and combine them with a LIGHTEN or ADD filter. You should now have an image which has black, red, green and yellow corners. Flatten it.
- Copy this image to another layer / whatever the term-of-choice is for your editor. Apply whatever displacement filter you want to it (maybe a fish eye, maybe a manual smudge, maybe a perspective transform, anything)
- Add a third layer between the two. Flood-fill it with dark yellow (128,128,0) and set it to ADD / ADDITION blend mode. Set the top layer to SUBTRACT / SUBTRACTION blend mode.

That's it. You should get a mostly yellow image which will function as a displacement map.

Update:

To use this in the example program (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/DisplacementMapFilter.html#includeExamplesSummary), replace the `createBitmapData` function with this:

```
private function createBitmapData():BitmapData {
    return myBitmapObject.bitmapData;
}
```

where `myBitmapObject` is the instance name (I think) of your displacement Bitmap. There are tidier ways of setting that up, but this is the easiest.

Comment: Hate to be a bother, but I can't get it to work. I stuck the whole function onto a frame and modified it. The name of instance of the displacement bitmap is Fisheye: http://pastebin.com/MegEvcnb. When I test the SWF, it runs as if there's no code.

Comment: Well, that really is just example code. You haven't invoked it, so it's just functions sat there waiting to run. Maybe if you remove lines 1,2 and 4 it will work, but as I say, I'm not familiar with non-pure-code projects. Try searching the web. Also I believe that code will apply the filter to the entire stage, rather than a particular object, and will only displace by 0.5 pixels in x and 30 in y, which you may not notice. While trying to get it running, try with much larger displacements (maybe 200) then tone them down once you know it's working.

Comment: Also you need to set componentY to BitmapDataChannel.GREEN, or it will use the red channel for both x and y, producing bizarre results.

Comment: Wow, I feel pretty stupid for not catching that. I got the functions to run, but the displacement bitmap is still in its visible state. Traces show that all the functions are being called, so I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Nothing in that code tells Fisheye to go invisible; it's used for the filter *and* displayed on the stage. You can add something to make it invisible though (I figured you'd keep it off-stage). And did you include the imports from the sample code? If not it's probably getting stuck in createFilter (you can trace at the *end* of createFilter to test). Also you might want to apply the filter to an object instead of the stage; change `filters = ...` to `myOtherObject.filters = ...` to do that.

Comment: I moved the Fisheye instance outside the stage, but now the filter's not doing anything to the object. The code itself seems to be fine syntax-wise, though, and everything executes properly.